# Class Inheritance in labeled property graph

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, arangodb

I use neo4j with Go lang and graphql on my project.

The problem I am encountering now is I need inheritance between the nodes (labels) same as it is usually found in owl or rdf files. I don't want to switch to rdf-stores, and I don't want to use the artificial "IS_A" relationship between nodes to solve this.

Is there any inbuilt capability of class inheritances in LPGs?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to indicate class inheritance in labelled property graphs like neo4j is to use multiple class labels on the same node.

If you already have different nodes for different classes, but want to avoid adding a lot of `IS_A` relationships, there are at least 2 approaches:

1. Combine the nodes belonging to the same resource in the class hierarchy into a single node, retaining all the original labels, properties, and relationships. There are APOC procedures that can help with this.
2. Create class hierarchy nodes labelled `Class` that explicitly specify the hierarchy between node labels. For example: `(:Class {name: 'Cat'})->[:IS_A]->(:Class {name: 'Mammal'})->[:IS_A]->(:Class {name: 'Animal'})`. You can then use this explicit `Class` hierarchy in your queries involving nodes `Cat`, `Mammal`, and `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to indicate class inheritance in labelled property graphs like neo4j is to use multiple class labels on the same node.

If you already have different nodes for different classes, but want to avoid adding a lot of `IS_A` relationships, you can combine the nodes belonging to the same resource in the class hierarchy into a single node with all the original labels, properties, and relationships. There are APOC procedures that can help with this.